# C# HttpListenerResponse HEAD метод, крашится

Tags: c#, http

Почему у меня программа крашится, если происходит HEAD метод?
И если можно, как исправить?

Ошибка:

> ```
> Количество байт для записи в поток превышает заданный размер Content-Length в байтах.
> ```

```
HttpListenerContext Context = Server.GetContext();
HttpListenerResponse Response = Context.Response;

switch (Context.Request.HttpMethod)
{
    case "GET":
        {
            string answer = "Hello, Student!";
            Response.ContentLength64 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(answer).Length;
            Response.OutputStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(answer), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(answer).Length); //С GET всё отлично кстати работает
            break;
        }
    case "HEAD":
        {
            string answer = "Head";
            Response.ContentLength64 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(answer).Count();
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.OutputStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(answer), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(answer).Count());//Вот ТУТ краш происходит
            break;
        }
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: А если так-же поменять `Count()` на `Length` как в GET?

Comment: @ГеннадийП изначально было как вы сейчас предлагаете (оно так же вылетало), это я уже альтернативный вариант использовал

Comment: Попробуйте без указания Content-Length для HEAD.

Comment: вообще  то HEAD не должен вызвращать тело. Content-Length должен, а само тело нет

Comment: ну и Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(answer.AsSpan());